# How do I print class name in a method?

Tags: python, class, object, oop

I made a method and called onto it with super() but I do not know how to write the name of the class in a print statement!

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Clothing(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def desc(self):
        pass


class Shirt(Clothing):
    def desc(self):
        x = input('Enter a color: ')
        y = input('Enter the size: ')

        print(f"Your {self} is: {x}\nAnd its size is: {y}")


class Jean(Shirt):
    def desc(self):
        super().desc()


# shirt = Shirt()
# shirt.desc()

jean = Jean()
jean.desc()
```

I tried printing self,
which, while it does kind of return the class name, it has this answer:

```
Your **<__main__.Jean object at 0x0000023E2C2D7D30>** is: red
And its size is: 32
```

Btw I started learning like a week ago so please do enlighten me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `instance.__class__.__name__`

You need to access the `__class__` attribute to get the class, then `__name__` to get the class name.

```py
class Foobar:
    ...

print(Foobar().__class__.__name__)
# Foobar
```

With your code, here is an example of usage:

```py
class Jean(Shirt):
    def desc(self):
        super().desc()

    def class_name(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

jean = Jean()
print(jean.class_name())
# Jean
```